# "Any help will be appreciated." - appropriate or not?

Tags: discussion

I don't know what to call these sentences that are often written at the end of questions, but here are some examples:

- "Could anyone give me some explanations on this problem? Thanks a lot!" - [Why does the constructor of java.util.Date act differently on parameters between int and long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22060637/why-does-the-constructor-of-java-util-date-act-differently-on-parameters-between)
- "Thanks in advance!" - [Java: Graphics 2d, will not draw fast enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22060601/java-graphics-2d-will-not-draw-fast-enough)
- "Thank you and More Power!" - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22060583/how-to-configure-two-different-schemas-in-glassfish
- "Please help" - [IO and doing logic take a long time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22060955/reading-from-file-and-performing-action-is-very-slow)
- "any suggestions?" - [Crypt cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22060525/crypt-cannot-be-resolved)

Is it OK for questions to contain these messages?

I've also seen some edits adding these, even when the original question did not have them. Is this OK as well?

Comment: That, and the various questions that are linked to it. Reading through all of it will probably provide a definitive answer.

Comment: I'd call them valedictions, but they're all fluff that adds no value to the question.